# Wordpress Advanced Search Plugin

Tags: wordpress, specifications, advanced-search

I want to design a Wordpress site that contains all of the usual Wordpress components (blog, contact us, image gallery, etc).  I want to have a separate section of the site for "Books" and "Articles".

Admins will be able to enter a book/article with its detailed information (title, author, reference, etc.).  I need to have a way for users (non admin) to be able to do an advanced search on these books entered by the Admin.

Should I use Wordpress for the entire site, and write a custom plugin for the book search piece?  OR Have a custom PHP page for the searching?  OR Is there a plugin that already exists where I could leverage Wordpress to do this advanced search for me?  Any information to point me in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Wordpress Plugin](http://www.zirona.com/software/wordpress-advanced-search/).  It should provide you with what you need within the bounds of Wordpress.  This should save time from having to write custom PHP code for this functionality.

There are probably other plugins available too that could work for you.  One of the benefits of open source is there is a lot of user created content.  This should help get you started.